# Momenjs formatter changes time from 00 to 03 hours

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Why `moment("2020-08-26T00:00:00Z").format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss Z')` gives "26.08.2020 **03:00:00** +03:00". I do understand addition of current timezone but why time is changed too?

[jsbin sample here](https://jsbin.com/yuduzoyuso/edit?html,js,console)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ISO 8601 format, [the "Z" at the end refers to the UTC+0 timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). `2020-08-26T00:00:00Z` therefore means the same as `2020-08-26T00:00:00+00:00`.

If you want to use another timezone in the constructor, specify it explicitly:

```js
moment('2020-08-26T00:00:00+03:00').format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss Z')
//                         ^^^^^^
// if the user agent's timezone is UTC+3,
// this will be formatted as "26.08.2020 00:00:00 +03:00"
```

If, on the other hand, you want to construct a UTC+0 datetime and format it in UTC+0, *ignoring the user agent's timezone*, use this (per your comment):

```js
moment("2020-08-26T00:00:00Z").utc().format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss Z")
//                            ^^^^^^
// this will _always_ be formatted as "26.08.2020 00:00:00 +00:00"
```

Comment: So the problem is incorrect format.. Thanks! ```moment("2020-08-26T00:00:00Z").utc().format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss Z")``` solved this. (I'm receiving date from backend in those format)

Comment: You answer is focused on timezone, but I was confused by incorrect hours. You helped me anyway

Comment: @Kseniia I think I may have misunderstood the question. I've edited the answer to incorporate your solution.